# How to recover a corrupted 3gpp record audio file?

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery

So I made 5 audio records using the default recorder in Android 4.4. All of them seem to have information because they have a size between 100MB-150MB. The problem is that some metadata was deleted, like length, bit rate, audio sample rate, etc. from all the files.

Because of this, I can't open the files. I want to be able to recover the file; I tried to use Audacity or Soundforge but it just plays static.

I read that by editing the hex I can modify the missing metadata but it didn't explain much more. Any help is welcome.

Comment: How about from a backup file... if you deleted the meta data then how else do you expect to get it back if it is gone and you do not have a backup or the source files to base it off of. Otherwise, look at a scripted solution or an app that can inspect the file contents and fill in any blanks for there metadata where applicable.

Comment: Have you tried opening in VLC? When certain file information is missing, VLC is generally quite capable of repairing the files, or at least still playing them and saving them to another format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a hexeditor to fix the missing information.

Try downloading HxD. This is a hex editor, and you can insert information.

What I suggest is do another short recording to gain the header information, and then see if you can insert that information into the beginning of your corrupt data

Comment: Thanks, i have downloaded the hxd and opened the audio, there is a chunk where only are 00 , i recorded an audio and open it with hdx but how can i solve the problem is still unknow to me

Comment: try comparing the two different audio files, and seeing what is similar? Perhaps that could be the header